# Get running processes for remote computers with username

Tags: powershell

I need to monitor when a process stops running for each user on remote machines.

I can get the processes and usernames for processes running on a machine:

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName
```

And I can get the processes running on remote machines (without the usernames):

```
Get-Process -ComputerName Test-PC
```

But I can't join the two together! For example this does not work:

```
Get-Process -ComputerName Test-PC -IncludeUserName
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You'll have to wrap the cmdlet inside a `Invoke-Command` scriptblock. Use the ` -IncludeUserName` switch in the scriptblock and the `-ComputerName` parameter on Invoke-Command

Comment: I'm really sorry but could you provide an example I've not done this before?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile now, but I see @Jawad already showed you what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example of running a script / command on a remote computer,

```
$processes = Invoke-Command -ComputerName Test-PC -scriptBlock { Get-Process -IncludeUserName }
```

This will give you all the processes with username from the remote computer. If you need to provide different credentials, you can use the `-Credential` switch.

[Documentation on Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1) - You should read up on this to get details on other switches.

Comment: @Dan, do mark the post as answered by clicking the ✔ under votes if this answered the question